# Trouble understanding in why the value of x is not changing in the last line?

Tags: python

[][1]

I was playing around with it and then I'm stuck understanding in the mutability of the list.

IN LINE, `b[2] = 22`, the value in list of `x` changes but after executing `b= [2,1,3]`, it doesn't change and its correct but after it,

I was trying to change x with `b[0] = 45` for second time which is not changing the list value of x, why?

[I'm using a python 3.7, I'm a beginner in python language. I was playing around with it and then I'm stuck understanding in the mutability of the list. IN LINE, b[2] = 22, the value in list of x changes but after executing b= [2,1,3], it doesn't change and its correct but after it, I was trying to change x with b[0] = 45 for second time which is not changing the list value of x, why?

a = [23]

b=[23,2,3]

x = [a,b]

b[2] = 22

x
  [[23], [23, 2, 22]]

b=[2,1,3]
  x
  [[23], [23, 2, 22]]

b[0] = 45

x
  [[23], [23, 2, 22]]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please don't post pictures of your code. Isntead, paste your code into the question and use the code formatting (indent code by four spaces)

Comment: So... what is your question? Can you provide a logical context?

Comment: Please read about [mcve], we can't help you without one

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: There used to be a picture of code in the question I am referring to

Let's take a look at this example which resembles what you are doing in your code:

```
a = [20]
b = [21,22,23]
x = [a,b]
```

you have created two lists and a third list, that contains these two lists. The thing to understand here is that both b and x[1] reference the **same** list.

```
b[0] = 0
```

therefore reuslts in `x==[[20],[0,22,23]]`. No big suprise, because with setting b[0] you also changed the value in the list x[1], as they reference the same list.
Now when you do

```
b = [1, 2, 3]
```

you are setting b to point to a **new** list, you are not changing what the original list b pointed to was, but are just renaming which list you want to call b. This then has no effect on what is in x[1], as it still points to the list [0, 22,23]

Comment: so, the second one doesn't effect on the changes or there will be a two list after the second one which can be pointed with other way.

Comment: The statement `b=[1, 2, 3]` does not affect the second element in the list `x`. You have three lists after that statement. One is the list a, which is the same as x[0], you have the list `b=[1, 2, 3]` and `x[1] = [0, 22, 23]`

Comment: b[0] = 45

x [[23], [23, 2, 22]]    what about this line, x list is not changing.

Comment: In that line you have already overwritten b to point to the list `[2,1,3]` instead of the previous `[23, 2, 22]`. You could do b=x[1] followd by b[0]=45 and see that x changes

Comment: Yeah, now it has changed , Thank you so much.